# Как сделать несколько ssl сертификатов в системе CentOS

Tags: linux, apache, centos, https, openssl

Существует ли какой то способ сделать несколько ssl сертификатов на одном физическом сервере, с одним ip адресом, но несколькими доменами. Задача чтобы соединение с сервером шифровалось. Проблема в том что , все доменные имена физически находятся на одном сервере, и имеют один и тот же физический адрес.

Нашел в интернете что есть технология - [Server_Name_Indication](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) . Но нужно это делать или нет, не понятно. Какая последовательность действий. Объясните пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно [здесь](https://certbot.eff.org/all-instructions), вы найдете решение. У меня certbot спокойно генерит сертификаты для 3х доменов на одной машине с одним ip, при этом они нормально распознаются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SNI понимают все современные браузеры. В эту сторону делать ничего не нужно. А к IP-адресу сертификат вообще никак не привязывается, то есть на одном адресе можно обслуживать сколько угодно доменов и любые из этих доменов можно уносить на другие адреса.

Учтите, что вам нужно будет сделать сертификаты для *всех* ваших доменов с поддержкой HTTPS. Самый простой способ — [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org)

Comment: понимаю что нужно будет сделать сертификат, а вот как его добавить в апач, и привязать к домену не понятно.

Comment: @spectre_it https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm, пример №1.